# Cómo ordenar un array de cadenas de forma descendente en PHP

Tags: php, php7

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el que el usuario inserta un texto en un textarea y he de separar el texto en palabras y luego mostrar los arrays ordenados, tanto de forma ascendente (alfabéticamente) como descendente (el alfabeto al revés), sin hacer distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Esto sería la parte de HTML:

```
<label for="textarea">Inserte el contenido del texto</label>
<br><br>
<textarea name="textarea" rows="20" cols="50"></textarea>
<br><br>
<label for="selectordenar"> Seleccione cómo quiere ordenar </label>
<select name="selectordenar" id="selectordenar">
    <option value="-1">Seleccione cómo quiere ordenar</option>
    <option value="ascendente">Orden Ascendente</option>
    <option value="descendente">Orden Descendente</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Ordenar" name="ordenar"> 

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Y esto la parte de PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['ordenar'])){ //Si he seleccionado ordenar

    $texto=$_POST['textarea']; //Cojo las palabras 

    $palabras=explode(" ",$texto); //Separo el texto en palabras mediante el método explode

    if(isset($_POST['selectordenar'])){

        $orden=$_POST['selectordenar']; 

        if($orden=="ascendente"){
            natcasesort($palabras); //Con la función natcasesort ordeno las palabras de forma alfabética de forma insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas
            print_r($palabras);
        } else if($orden=="descendente"){
            print_r("Has seleccionado ordenar de forma descendente");
            natcasesort($palabras); //Con la función natcasesort ordeno las palabras de forma alfabética de forma insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas
            array_reverse($palabras); //Invierto el array, ya que tiene que estar ordenado de forma descendente
            print_r($palabras); //Lo muestro en pantalla

        } else if ($orden==-1){
            print_r("Tienes que seleccionar una forma de ordenar el texto"); 
        }





    }
```

El caso es que para la forma ascendente OK, pero para la ordenación descendente me hace el natcasesort pero no me hace el array_reverse. Entiendo, de todas formas, que debe haber alguna forma de ordenar de forma descendente directamente sin discriminar mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero no he encontrado nada. ¿Alguna idea? Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función [array_reverse()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-reverse.php) no modifica de forma directa el array al igual que lo hace `natcasesort()`, de modo que **tendrás que especificar dónde quieres almacenar el nuevo array** con el orden reverso:

**Simplemente cambia:**

```
array_reverse($palabras);
```

**Por:**

```
$palabras = array_reverse($palabras);
```